# Does Google play store policy allow to get phone number

Tags: android, google-play

I am a android programming beginner.

I am creating an app that takes the phone number programatically from the device.

Does Google allow this or will my app be restricted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the enforcement opf policies of a distribution channel, not programming.

Comment: I agree with CommonsWare

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, in order to get the phone number from the device, you will need to specify the appropriate Permission in your AndroidManifest.  This is perfectly acceptable to do, and this is allowable in the Play Store.

This likely will effect the rating you can assign to your app, because gathering personal information (like phone number) is not allowed in apps that are rated for "everyone".

Bottom line, you can get the phone number, and the Permissions model insures that you don't do this without the users knowledge.